# How to display Configurable Swatches in Home Page Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, configurable-product

I have a list of products on my homepage and I'm having a hard time on how to display the configurable/color swatches along the products on my homepage. The configurable/color swatches on my catalog list are working fine. I'm guessing that I just need to configure my layout but I don't know how to. I'm using RWD theme and Magento 1.9.

Anyone, please help me. Thanks!

UPDATE!!

So I found out that this

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $j(document).on('product-media-loaded', function() {
        ConfigurableMediaImages.init('<?php echo $this->getImageType(); ?>');
        <?php foreach ($this->getProductImageFallbacks() as $imageFallback): ?>
        ConfigurableMediaImages.setImageFallback(<?php echo $imageFallback['product']->getId(); ?>, $j.parseJSON('<?php echo $imageFallback['image_fallback']; ?>'));
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        $j(document).trigger('configurable-media-images-init', ConfigurableMediaImages);
    });
</script>
```

in app/design/frontend//default/configurableswatches/catalog/media/js.phtml

is the cause of the problem.

But before that, I paste this in my local.xml

```
<cms_index_index translate="label">
    <update handle="product_list"/> 
    <reference name="content">
         <block type="configurableswatches/catalog_media_js_list" name="configurableswatches.media.js.list" />
     </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Then I found out that the products don't populate its small images.
If you noticed, there's a for loop in the javascript above, but it doesn't work because **getProductImageFallbacks()** returns NULL.

This is what I put on my CMS content (Homepage)

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="5" category_id="21" template="catalog/product/homepage-list.phtml"}}
```

In app/code/local/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Block/Catalog/Media/Js/Abstract.php line 69 in **public function getProductImageFallbacks($keepFrame = null)**

This `$products = $this->getProducts();` gives me NULL. That's why it can't give the correct image fallback.

Still waiting for an answer. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code :

```
<?php
$categoryId = 3 //your category id's;
$collection = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)
->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('status',1);

foreach($collection as $pro):
$productAttributeOptions =
$pro->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($pro);
?>
<h3 class="product-name"><?php  echo $pro->getName(); ?></h3>

<?php
```

// Provides extra blocks on which to hang some features for products in the
list

// Features providing UI elements targeting this block will display
directly below the product name

```
if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
$_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
$_nameAfterChild =
$this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
$_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
}
}
?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer. I'll try that. I created another list.phtml (I named it homepage-list.phtml) and from the content of my homepage in CMS section I wrote

{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="5" category_id="21" template="catalog/product/homepage-list.phtml"}}. I'm just gonna add the above code to my homepage-list.phtml right?

Answer (score 0):

To show configurable swatch on Home Page in Feature Products List, follow the below steps:

Make your own list.phtml file for custom products list
In your list.phtml file select place where you want to show configurable swatches and paste below code:

```
    $_nameAfterChild = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product_list.swatches');
    $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
    echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
```

Include this file in Home Page in CMS using below code:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="5" category_id="21" template="catalog/product/homepage-list.phtml"}}
```

In `local.xml` file in your theme paste below code:

```
    cms_index_index
         update handle="product_list"/
    /cms_index_index
```